# Write only accessors in C#

Tags: c#

How do the so called write only accessors works, for instance  `Discount`?

```
class CableBill
{
    private int rentalFee;
    private int payPerViewDiscount;
    private bool discount;

    public CableBill(int rentalFee)
    {
        this.rentalFee = rentalFee;
        discount = false;
    }

    public bool Discount
    {
        set
        {
            discount = value;
            if (discount)
                payPerViewDiscount = 2;
            else
                payPerViewDiscount = 0;
        }
    }

    public int CalculateAmount(int payPerViewMoviesOrdered)
    {
        return (rentalFee - payPerViewDiscount) * payPerViewMoviesOrdered;
    }
}
```

When I write

```
CableBill january = new CableBill(4);
MessageBox.Show(january.CalculateAmount(7).ToString());
```

The return value is 28

My question is:
How does the program know that `payPerViewDiscount=0`?I never used the `Discount` property when I initialized my object

Comment: If you never initialize an int, its value will be 0.

Comment: Is that even a valid property? if it is, I can't really see the point in having it (A method would be more suitable imo)

Comment: `default(int) == 0` and `default(bool) == false`

Comment: why the down votes on answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All members of a class are automatically initialized with the [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) value of their type. For an `int` this is `0`.

By the way, write-only properties are bad style (according to [Microsoft's design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx)). You should probably use a method instead.

Comment: Write only properties are only bad style if they have side-effects.  I agree with your answer, but have to disagree with this premise :)

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't initialize an `int`, its default value will be equal to 0

```
int myInt = new int();
```

The preceding statement has the same effect as the following statement:

```
int myInt = 0;
```

[Default Values Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)

In c# you can use the `default` keyword to determine default values of types.

For example:

```
default(bool)
default(int)
default(int?)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but though this answer is correct in the context of this question, it is incorrect in general. If you don't initialize an `int` local variable, the compiler will not let you access its value in any way at all. If you don't initialize an `int` class field, then yes, its default value is zero.

Comment: @moez No offense, I down voted because you basically gave the same answer as Sebastian who posted first. Now you expanded the answer, I reverted my down vote.

Answer (score -1):

All the **primitive types** like

> int, double, long etc

are assigned default value automatically.

```
default value for int=0;
default value for char='\0';
default value for char='\0';
```

Forexample you don't know default value of some primitive type 
you can access them like this

```
 public void PassDefaultValues(bool defaultBool, DateTime defaultDateTime)
 {
   // Nothing
 }
```

and you can call it like this

```
        public void PassDefaultValues(default(bool), default(DateTime));
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because default bool is set to `false`, and then if goes the route of setting internal `this.discount` to be false, makes a check and goes into else which sets `payPerViewDiscount` to 0. One should always call write only accessors in constructor by setting the default value.

```
public bool Discount
    {
        set
        {
            this.discount = value;
            if (this.discount)
                this.payPerViewDiscount = 2;
            else
                this.payPerViewDiscount = 0;
        }
    }
```

You should be setting default to `this.Default` and not to underlying property.

```
public CableBill(int rentalFee)
    {
        this.rentalFee = rentalFee;
        this.Discount = false;
    }
```

Comment: the `Discount` property is never used.

Comment: It's not a problem at all. The question premise is invalid, he would get the same result if there was no property at all. It's rather why the default value of `payPerViewDiscount` is 0. As the question states: _I never used the Discount property_, so the OP is aware of this.

Comment: @Default so you are stating that next guy having this problem who will find this article shouldn't fix the underlying cause of miscalculation?

Comment: More or less.. If it were up to me I'd probably change the whole question to remove the stuff about setterproperties. The fact that the accepted answer has to do with default value to me means that the OP thought that the setterproperty was called but it was just a default value all along. The title and the question have nothing to do with each other (that's why I said that the question premise is invalid).

Comment: @Default well under this logic I suppose I was indeed asking for downvote. I must have forgotten that we are here for the points and not to actually help to fix stuff, thanks for straightening me.